# Deplhi Эмулировать сообщение TWMKey в обработчике TDxBarManager.OnHableKey

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Добрый день!

Есть форма с главным меню в виде DevExpess-овского' **TDxBar**. В меню есть пункт с **ShortCut**.

Дальше на форме есть несколько гридов, с **TPopUpMenu** меню в которых есть также пункты с таким же **ShortCut**, но выполняющие другое действие.

**TDxBar**, как известно, перехватывает все события нажатия клавиш и сам их  переваривает, ни до грида, ни до **Application.OnMessage** дело не доходит.

У **TDxBarManager** есть событие:

```
OnHandleKey(Sender: TObject; AKey: Word;  AShift: TShiftState; var AHandled: Boolean)
```

В нем пока у меня получается перебрать все пункты меню на форме, найти тот у которого **ShortCut** совпадает с нажатыми клавишами и выполнить его метод, но как-то это работает задумчиво, да и из-за того что гридов несколько не получается выйти на активный.

Нельзя ли как-то из этого события вызвать метод **IsShortCut** у **TPopUpMenu**? Для этого я так понимаю надо как-то сформировать сообщение **TWMKey**. Но как превратить в него имеющиеся запчасти, пока не очень понимаю. Ну или каким-то еще образом найти пункт меню у активного грида?

Comment: `AHandled := False;` знаете что делает, пробовали ставить, не помогает?

Comment: Он при входе в процедуру `false`. А дальше уходит и срабатывает на пункт меню.

Comment: Нашел решение. Обход в цикле всех `TForm.Components` и вызов у каждого 'TPopUpMenu.IsShortCut' С передачей `TWMKey` [созданного так](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=220).

Comment: Разместите как ответ?